# Using batch file to input values into exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, input, exe

I have a exe program, named `a.exe`. After opening it, I need to click the `ENTER` button to process. Then it displays a list of items,looks like following:

> 1. item1
> 2. item2
> 3. item3

I need firstly input "`1`" to choose the `item 1`, and then input value "`11`" to this item. Then I need input "`3`" to choose the `item 3`, and then input value "`33`" to this item.

Actually, I have to repeat the procedure above 100 times, input different values per time. I am unwilling to input manually for 100 times.

I was wondering, can i use a batch file to input values into this program?
How to write the code? (P.S. I know very little about batch code)

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use an input file (.txt)?

Comment: Did you develop the program in question? If you did you can create a type of simple api program like a windows console app. This can accept an array of strings on start which can be the values in the order you need then have the main project or one of them referenced to construct an object based on the values or simply pass them on as a string or int or whatever you need.

Comment: Welcome to the site. you may be able to use [redirection or pipe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). There are also [macro recording/replay programs](http://alternativeto.net/software/perfect-macro-recorder/?license=opensource&platform=windows) in some versions of Windows. You should provide your version of Windows in your question

Comment: Is this a console program or has it got a gui interface? It's possible that creating a simple text file with lines like `1` `11` `3` `33` etc (one number per line) and then using the command `a.exe <yourtextfilename.txt` will work, but no guarantees  - we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

To start an application from a batch file you will do something like this

```
start application.exe
```

to send parameters to the application you just need to put the parameters after
the application so if you wanted to open a website in IE you would do it like this

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE www.google.com
```

If you cannot use parameters in your application anothe thing you could do is have your application read from a text file to start it. Because batch can write to a text file like so.

```
echo start > input.txt
```